# Pause the execution of exe of a C code

Tags: c, deployment, exe

I have developed a simple console utility in C which parses various text files.

IDE - Code Blocks
OS - windows

I intend to distribute its executable.

The executable works fine, however unlike when executed from the IDE, the execution does not pause/wait for keystroke at the end of execution.

I tried using getchar()/system("pause"), but the execution doesn't pause there.

Is there an alternative to wait for keystroke before ending execution, so that the user can view the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

> getchar();

twice , because its very likely that last '\n' newline character will get consumed by your getchar().

or use

> scanf(" %c");

with that extra space

at the end of your file .

Comment: Thanks Namit,

I tried getchar as you said twice but the execution didnt stop for the keypress.

Comment: I tried your suggestion as shown below

`int main()
{
    node *temp1,*temp2;
    char script[255],ch;
    char *dev;
    FILE *fp;

   //file reading and parsing logic
   // no input from the user
   // only printf displaying the progress/errors

    free(head);
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}`

similarly I tried

scanf(" %c",&ch);// with the space

It works fine when I run it from the IDE
with the exe it doesn't pause.

Comment: Hey Namit,

I don't know what changed, from my previous execution, but its working.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how other parts of your code receives input from the user (i.e. reading from `stdin`).

The `getchar()` approach will work fine if your program is not reading anything from the user, or is reading using `getchar()`.

A general guideline, however, is to be consistent in style of input from every stream.   Style of input refers to character-oriented (functions like `getchar()`), line-oriented (like `fgets()`), formatted (functions like `scanf()`), or unformatted (like `fread()`).    Each one of those functions does different things depending on input - for example `getchar()` will read a newline as an integral value,  `fgets()` will leave a newline on the end of the string read if the buffer is long enough,  `scanf()` will often stop when it encounters a newline but leave the newline in the stream to be read next.

The net effect is that different styles of input will interact, and can produce strange effects (e.g. data being ignored, not waiting for input as you are seeing).

For example, if you are using `scanf()`, you should probably also use `scanf()` to make your program wait at the end.   Not `getchar()` - because, in practice, there may well be a newline waiting to be read, so `getchar()` will return immediately, and your program will not pause before terminating.

There are exceptions to the above (e.g. depending on what format string is used, and what the user inputs).   But as a rule of thumb:  be consistent in the manner you are reading from `stdin`, and the user will have to work pretty hard to stop your program pausing before terminating.

An easier alternative, of course, is to run the program from the command line  (e.g. the CMD.EXE command shell).   Then the shell will take over when your program terminates, the program output will be visible to the user, so your program does not need to pause.

Comment: thanks Peter,

however I don't accept any input from the user, nowhere in the code have I used getchar(), scanf(), gets().
The code just deals with File read/write operations using fscanf() and fprintf().

Comment: You're going to need to provide a SMALL but COMPLETE (in the sense that other people can compile, link, and execute) sample of code that illustrates your problem.   The only way `getchar()` will not pause is if there is input pending in `stdin` - whether from the user, `stdin` being redirected, being piped in by another process, etc.   There must therefore be something else you haven't described that is happening in your program, or the environment you're running it in, or that the user is doing to cause the behaviour.

Comment: Using getchar() twice as suggested fixed the issue.

Thanks

Comment: That's a sign that the program is being given input via `stdin`, despite your claim that it isn't.   The fact your symptom is changing also supports that assertion.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `system("pause")` since it's not portable. `getchar` should work on the other hand. Can you post some code? Maybe there's something on the keyboard buffer that's being consumed by your one and only `getchar` call.

Comment: Thanks Pablo,

I tried this
`    free(head);
    getchar();
    getchar();// a 2nd getchar as suggested by Namit above
    return 0;
}`

but the execution won't pause.